# SAPUI import javascript class as library in launchpad

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to upload to the SAPUI app a pure java script file that contains 4 classes, I want to use this classes globally on all controllers, at the moment I set the file in manifest, in a local host everything works fine and I can use those classes and their methods,

when I build the project to the launchpad the app does not recognize the class And in the network the file not loaded, I saw that the builder adds "-dbg" to the file name so I changed in manifest, now I see in the network that the file is loaded and still can not use the classes.

manifest:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOQPV.png)

LocalHost network
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdxup.png)

use the class in the local host
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCpng.png)

launchpad network after add in manifest "-dbg" to file name, else it wont load the file.

in lanuchpad:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpNMv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mquow.png)

I can't find how to import those classes . Any ideas?

Thanks and Best regards,

Gal Tager

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest organizing a pure java script file as a [module](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/00737d6c1b864dc3ab72ef56611491c4.html).

For example, there is a project manifest.json

```
{
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "sap.app": {
      "_version": "1.1.0",
      "id": "com.work.myproject",
      "type": "application", ...
```

a GsIntegration.js file in a project path ./module/GsIntegration.js

the module can be loaded in a control:

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller", "com/work/GsIntegration"],
   function(Controller, GsIntegration) ...
```